# How to sum some unknowns to make underdetermined system determined with $A$ being a binary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

For a underdetermined system $Ax=b$, $A$ is a binary matrix, for example:
$$A=\left[\begin{matrix}1&1&0&0\\1&0&1&0\\1&0&1&1\end{matrix}\right],$$
and $x=[x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4]^T$.

Let $x'=[x_1', x_2', x_3']^T$, where $x_1' = x_1 + x_2$, $x_2' = x_1 + x_3$ and $x_3'=x_4$; the 
$$A'=\left[\begin{matrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&1&1\end{matrix}\right].$$
It can be found that $A'x'=b$ is a determined system , and $A'x' = Ax = b$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^4 $.

My question is how to find $x'$ that
$$
\begin{aligned}
 & \min \sum_{i<j} |term(x_i') \cap term(x_j')| \\
s.t. \quad  & A'x'= Ax, x=[x_1, x_2, ..., x_n]^T \\
 & A \text{ and } A' \text{ are two binary matrices} \\
 & x_i' \text{ is the sum of subset of } \{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\} \\
 & A'x'=b \text{ is a determined system}
\end{aligned}
$$
$x'_i$ is the sum of subset of $\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\}$, thus $term(x'_i)$ is that subset (i.e. terms for addition).

Comment: What do you mean by "find $x'$ with the given binary matrix $A$"?

Comment: I have modified the question, please refer to it.

Comment: This question is missing some information. What do you mean by $A'x' = b$ is equivalent to $Ax = b$? What is $term(x_i')$? Your definition of $x'$ is not clear and does not seem to make sense in your example.

Comment: There is a related question, which, in my opinion, is much clearer, maybe you will be interested. Please refer to [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1575712/how-many-subsets-of-unknowns-whose-sum-can-be-determined-by-the-underdetermined)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you are going to solve the system on ordinary $\mathbb{R}^n$ with usual rules of addition and multiplication (**Case A**), or on the two-element Boolean algebra i.e. $\{0,1\}^n$ with Boolean arithmetic (**Case B**), so here I study both cases. My conclusion (roughly stated) is "***In the case B, the only way to meet the requirement is a trivial one (or its permutation), while we may be able to improve more in the Case A***."

If my understanding is correct, you are asking how to find an invertible matrix $A^{\prime}\in X^{m\times m}$ ($X=\mathbb{R}$ for the **Case A**, or $X=\{0,1\}$ for the **Case B**) and a binary matrix $B\in X^{n\times m}$ such that $A^{\prime}B=A$, for a given undetermined linear system $Ax=b$, where $x\in X^n$ and $A\in X^{n\times m}\ (n>m)$. In addition, the first requirement to minimize the overlap in the use of $x_i$ in constructing $x_i^{\prime}$ (clearer definition will be given below) makes the problem somewhat nontrivial.

First, notice that if we set $A^{\prime}$ to be a permutation matrix (which is obviously invertible), we can easily construct a binary matrix $B$ by $B=A^{\prime T}A$. However, *a permutation of rows does not change the number of occurences of $1$ for each column*. It means that a permutation does not change the following quantity (whom we would like to minimize, to my understanding) either:$$n(B):=\sum_{i<j}g_i\cdot g_j=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{||h_i||_1(||h_i||_1-1)}{2};$$ where $g_i\ (i=1,2,\cdots,m)$ is the $i$th row vector of $B$, $||h_i||_1\ (i=1,2,\cdots,n)$ is 1-norm (sum of the elements in this case) of the $i$th column vector of $B$, and $\cdot$ denotes a usual inner product. Unfortunately, in the **Case B**, it is known that permutation matrices are the only matrices which have inverses (see e.g. Section 4 of [K. H. Kim and F. W. Roush, Linear Algebra and its Applications **22**, 247 (1978)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379578900757) for some known results about an inverse of Boolean matrix) and therefore we cannot decrease $n(B)$ any further. Note that the example you provided, if defined on a two-element Boolean algebra, violates the requirement that $A^{\prime}x^{\prime}=b$ be determined (Consider e.g. $b=(0,1,1)^T$).

In the **Case A**, on the other hand, $n(B)$ can be decreased if there exists $i\in \{1,2,\cdots,m\}$, a subset $U\subset \{1,2,\cdots,i-1,i+1,\cdots,m\}$, and non-zero $e^{\prime T}\in \{0,1\}^n$ such that $$e_i=\sum_{j\in U}e_j+e^{\prime};$$ where $e_i$ is the $i$th row vector of $A$, all of which are linearly independent from each other (otherwise a requirement "$A^{\prime}$ should be invertible" will be violated). When this condition is satisfied, we can decrease $n(B)$ (starting from $A^{\prime}=I$ and $B=A$) by using $e^{\prime}$ instead of $e_i$ for $i$th column vector of $B$ and putting 1 to $j(\in U)$th element of the $i$th row vector of $A^{\prime}$ (note that $e^{\prime}$ has fewer non-zero elements than $e_{i}$ by construction). Since the requirements that both $A^{\prime}$ and $B$ should be a binary matrix are strong in the **Case A**, repeating the forementioned procedure until there no longer exists a pair $i,j\in\{1,2,\cdots,m\}$ such that $(g_i)_k\ge(g_j)_k\ \mathrm{for}\ \forall k\in\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ suffices for obtaining an optimal $n(B)$.

I show one example: consider a undetermined system $Ax=b$ with $$A=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right).$$ While the trivial (identical) transformation $A^{\prime}=I,\ B=A$ gives $n(B)=10$, $$A^{\prime}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\1 & 1 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right),\ B=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right)$$ gives $n(B)=1$. We can see from $B$ that the appropriate $x^{\prime}$ which fully satisfies the requirements is $x_1^{\prime}=x_1+x_2$, $x_2^{\prime}=x_3$, $x_3^{\prime}=x_2+x_4$ and $x_4^{\prime}=x_5$. Of course, this is one of the "luckiest" case. There are cases where we cannot reduce $n(B)$ at all (the limitation may be more or less relaxed if we allow the elements of $B$ to take $-1$).

I apologize for a very long reply... I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your time and patience. I want to solve this system  on ordinary $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $A$ and $A'$ being binary matrices; moreover, $B$ is also binary matrix, but I think $A'B=A$ uses two-element Boolean algebra. And I have some questions: 1) in the 2nd paragraph, I think you mean $A,B \in X^{m \times n}$; 2) I don't quite understand the describtion of procedure to obtain $A'$, for example using $e'$ which has same size of $B$'s row vector to  replace its column vector (relpacing its row vector seems cannot reproduce your example, too).

Comment: May be a step-by-step explaination of how to get the $A'$ and $B$ in your example can help me understand, thanks a lot.

Comment: Please refer to the example of the question [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1575712/how-many-subsets-of-unknowns-whose-sum-can-be-determined-by-the-underdetermined), I don't think your procedure would get the optimal answer to that $A$. I think maybe my question is neither **Case A** nor **Case B**.

Comment: Thank you very much for your careful reading and quick reply. I appreciate there are many typos/mistakes, and so I will revise my answer later (I don't have enough time right now, sorry). Just a quick comment about your new question: The question you kindly linked is close to **Case A**; once you get $A=A^{\prime}B$, resulting row vectors of $B$ seem to be what you are looking for. Two differences are that you don't require $A^{\prime}$ to be a binary matrix and you don't (explicitly) require resulting row vectors of $B$ to have minimum overlap, if my understanding is correct.

Comment: Yes, you are right. $A'$ is not required to be a binary matrix in the linked question. However, in my opinion, your method proposed here can't get the $[1,0,0,0,0,0]^T$ as a row vector of $B$ for that question, or may be I just don't quite understand your method.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Now I see your point. My current method (if described correctly) does nothing to a matrix $A$ such that none of the row vectors ($i$th row vector) succeed other row vectors ($j$th row vector; in a sense that every $k$th element of $i$th vector is equal to or greater than that of $j$th vector). I believe my method can/should be improved in this respect, and it will be discussed in the revised version of my answer.